# Get fields of empty struct slice in Go

Tags: reflection, go

I have a function

```
func (r *render) foo(v interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    fields := structs.Fields(val.Index(0).Interface())

...
```

Which takes a slice of structs and tries to get the fields of v, 
however if v is empty then "val.Index(0)" crashes the program. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check first if you have a slice to begin with, then check if you have an empty slice, and you probably should check that you have a struct too while you're at it: ([example](http://play.golang.org/p/r2PWqZoEbi))

```
val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
if val.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
    fmt.Println("not a slice")
    return
}

if val.Len() == 0 {
    fmt.Println("empty slice")
    return
}

if val.Index(0).Kind() != reflect.Struct {
    fmt.Println("not a slice of structs")
    return
}

fields := structs.Fields(val.Index(0).Interface())
...
```

If you only want the fields from a struct *type*, regardless of if the slice is empty, you can use the slice type's `Elem` method to extract it ([example](http://play.golang.org/p/kp_7C4hEwP))

```
// get the internal type of the slice
t := val.Type().Elem()
if t.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
    fmt.Println("not a struct")
    return
}

fmt.Println("Type:", t)
for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
    fmt.Println(t.Field(i).Name)
}
```

Comment: Well I know that It's always going to be a slice, either empty or not. However I need to be able to get the fields of the slice elements type regardless.

Comment: @tommy_p1ckles: Your question was about a crash when the slice is empty, so you need to ensure that it isn't. What else do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I guess I worded it poorly. My function takes a slice of structs and I need to be able to get the names of all the fields of the struct, this isn't a problem when the struct is nonempty as the code "fields := structs.Fields(val.Index(0).Interface())" does that, however if the slice is empty then this approach doesn't work since theres no first element to look at.

Comment: @tommy_p1ckles: OK, I see. I added how to get the type from within a slice.